# change the static IP address to domain name

Tags: web-hosting, domains, ip-address

I have a static IP and hosted my site in this.Working fine. But I want to change the URL name (static IP) to a domain name. I have one domain name already registered.

I have `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/` but I want to use something like `http://www.mydomain.com`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do two things:

1. Create A-record with name 'www' in your DNS zone, which points to your IP
2. Review your website/webserver settings and add `www.mydomain.com` as host name for your site (as soon as single web server can host multiple sites - it must know which name[s] are bound to each site)

And you have to wait some time as DNS data refresh over internet - from 1 hour to 24 or even more - depending on TTL parameter in DNS. For newly added record is must be fast (as soon as there was no this record before and nothing is cached).

Also you may add A-record without name (with the same IP) to DNS and add 'mydomain.com' (without www) name to your site - it will be accessible by `http://www.mydomain.com` and `http://mydomain.com` addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your domain panel and find `Record A`. In your `Record A` just insert your IP address. that's it. it will take approx 24 hours to active your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the nameservers of your domain name as well in order to point to the IP address.

A record also can be updated to point to the IPv4 address assigned to you.

The format for A record is:

**example.com IN A xx.xx.xx.xx**

Answer (score 0):

Please just kindly point your domain to your name server and the DNS will resolve in the next 12-24 hours. Then, you'll be able to browse your domain.